# .Net Custom Components "disappear" after file save

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I might have a hard time explaining this because I am at a total loss for what is happening so I am just looking for some guidance.  I might be a bit wordy because I don't know exactly what is the relevant information.

I am developing a GUI for a project that I am working on in using .Net (C#)

Part of the interface mimics, exactly, what we do in another product.  For consistency reasons, my boss wants me to make it look the same way. So I got the other software and basically copied and pasted the components into my new GUI.

This required me to introduce a component library (the now defunct Graphics Server GSNet, so I can't go to them for help) so I could implement some simple graphs and temperature/pressure "widgets."

The components show up fine, and when I compile, everything seems to work fine.  However, at some point during my programming it just breaks.  Sometimes the tab that these components are on starts throwing exceptions when I view the designer page (A missing method exception) so it won't display.  Sometimes JUST those components from the GSNet library don't show up.  Sometimes, if I try to run it, I get a not-instantiated exception on one of their lines of code in the designer code file.  Sometimes I can't view the designer at all.

No matter what I do I can't reverse it.  Even if I undo what I just did it won't fix it.  If it happens, I have to revert to a backup and start over again.

So I started to backup pretty much every step.  I compile it and it works.  I comment out a line of code, save it, and then uncomment that same line of code (so I am working with the same exact code) and the components all disappear.  It doesn't matter what line of code I actually comment out, as long as it is in the same project that these components are being used.

I pretty much have to use the components. . . so does anyone have any suggestion or where I can look to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is a read-only bin directory.  I've found that .NET has trouble if the interop libraries in the bin directory are read-only.  Read-only interops generally prevent controls using those interops from displaying in the form designer and thus mess up compilation (if you do a full build anyway).  A rebuild might let you get the app running and then fail when it reaches the part using the read-only interop.

This may or may not be your problem but it's all that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late to the game, but I just ran into this same problem.

I'd pulled down one of our applications from SVN, and when I first tried to open the main form for editing, I was prompted with the custom component not being defined in the software, even though I could plainly see it as a class.  I was given a choice to ignore it, which I did, and the custom control promptly disappeared from the form (still showed up in the project).

So at the suggestion of my colleague, I deleted the instance from my hard drive, and re-checked it out from SVN.  Before i did anything else, I built the project for both release & debug, and that fixed the problem.

Maybe this'll help someone else who finds this SO question when they run into this.